# how to create bulk repositories under Organization in git hub in single shot?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to create bulk repositories at single shot in GitHub under Organization through script. for example if I provide input in a JSON file and using any script preferably shell , is it possible to create repositories?
I have gone through google, I find a way top clone all at once , but couldnt find to create repositories. Any help is much appreciated.

```
ex: 
Organization1:
{

  {
    reponame:"repo1";
    descriptio:"some desc",
          },

  {
   reponame:"repo2";
    descriptio:"some desc",
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. There a few ways to do this. One way is through using [GitHub REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/). To help people looking at this to provide high quality answers, please look at the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and consider updating your question with a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks Hafiz for Promt response

Comment: Hi i found a easy solution can achieve using curl command . i have created multiple commands in shell script file and executed using git bash         command: curl -i -H "Authorization: token f91f15ba61fc1e2d682500accb5836cdc034f(your token)" -d "{ \"name\": \"nameof repo\", \"auto_init\": true, \"private\": false, \"gitignore_template\": \"nanoc\" }" https://api.github.com/orgs/orgName/repos